# is it possible to adjust RoundedRectangle's width according to Button label's width?

Tags: swiftui

I have this Button with RoundedRectangle, and it has fixed width (and height), but I want to calculate the width based on the Button's content. Is it possible?

```swift
ZStack {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
        .frame(width: 170, height: 50) // <- I want this WIDTH to be calculated
    
    Button {
        viewModel.startNewGame()
    } label: {
        Text("New Game")
        Image(systemName: "return")
    }
    .font(.title2)
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
}
```

I was thinking of using Geometry Reader, but I am new to SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ZStack` try `background`

```
        Button {
        } label: {
            Text("New Game")
            Image(systemName: "return")
        }
        .font(.title2)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .padding()
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
        }
```